# Подсказки кода eclipse c++

Tags: eclipse

Создаю переменную. Когда начинаю вводить первые символы имени этой переменной в месте её использования в коде, то я не вижу подсказки кода.

Как настроить подсказку кода, чтобы получилось как на картинке?

[image: Чтобы получилось как на картинке]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению нельзя сделать это полностью автоматически, но при нажатии ctrl+space можно. Для этого в меню Windows -> Preferences -> C++ -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced и Windows -> Preferences -> C++ -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced нужно поставить галочки где нужно (Желательно везде).